# How do I create button with dynamic parameters onclick event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a DataTable and some rows on it. Each row has an Edit button and each Edit button calls myFunction() where I edit the data of that row only. The problem is here: I edit one row, then a second one, then I try to edit the first one again but it contains the data of the first one in onClick event parameters.

```
edit_admin_request(this_,data_){
  //open modal and edit the users data. Modal has a button which when clicked calls myFunction()
}

edit_admin_object = {}; //this is defined outside of the function

function myFunction(){
   ...

   edit_admin_object['name'] = name_.value;
   edit_admin_object['email'] = email_.value;
   var edit_button = '<button type="button" id="buttons" onclick="edit_admin_request(this,JSON.stringify(edit_admin_object))" name="edit_admin">Edit</button>';
   var rowNode = myTable.row(window.rowindex).data(['<b>' + name_.value + '</b>', admin_role.value == '0' ? 'Admin' : 'Superadmin', phone_.value, email_.value, location_name, edit_button]).draw()

   ...
 }
```

I think I know where the problem is but I dont know how to fix it. The `edit_admin_object` object is defined globally and then each created button is taking the same object. But what else can I actually do in this case?!

UPDATE:
I think I have a better clue now of what's wrong. It might be the string syntax when creating a new button.

New UPDATE.

I came closer to the problem, now I know for sure the way I am stringifying the object and passing it as parameter is the problem.

```
var edit_button = '<button type="button" id="buttons" onclick="edit_admin_request(this,\'' + JSON.stringify(edit_admin_object) + '\')" name="edit_admin">Edit</button>';
```

P.S. see the syntax changes I made.

Comment: why have you defined the object globally?

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA if I dont define it globally, the new button doesn't take any parameters .

Comment: You can clone the object in myFuntion and then use that to pass to the edit_admin_request function.

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA it doesn't work, it just doesn't pass any parameters if its not globally. I think there is something wrong with the string syntax I am using when creating new button. Please take a look at that.

Comment: I think you are trying to create a button where you want to attach a clicklistener to it. Try this to create button ` ```var edit_button = `<button type="button" id="buttons" onclick=${edit_admin_request.bind(this,JSON.stringify(edit_admin_object))}" name="edit_admin">Edit</button>`;``` which is basically using string literals.

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA it doesn't work. after its created it doesn't call the function at all.

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA how do I do it using `createElement`?

Comment: Check this https://gist.github.com/vyasriday/d2de697ec12070dabcbc144516e0b8a0

Comment: I think by passing this to the function you are trying to bind the this to it. But actually you are calling the function in the click handler itself by passing the this. The way you have written it will call the function itself and onClick will get what is returned from the click handler function. You need to use `.bind` to bind the function to this.

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA nope. `this` is correct. The problem is on the Stringify because if I try to give a static parameter ike ["test"] it works, it does call the function and it does pass the "test" parameter.

Comment: then try using string literals and remove bind from there. ```var edit_button = `<button type="button" id="buttons" onclick=${edit_admin_request(this,JSON.stringify(edit_admin_object))}" name="edit_admin">Edit</button>` ```
I hope this solves your problem. If it doesn't conact me on twitter at @vyasriday as discussion id going too long. I might not be able to get the context of your problem

Comment: @HRIDAYESHSHARMA please see my edited post